# special characters in Java

Tags: java, utf-8

I have a form (struts 1) that is being validated and during the validation I have been asked to remove MS Word's curly single and double quote marks. Seems like such a simple request and I am tearing my hair out over it.

My test text is `’ “ ”`.

First of all, I found that when I run my code in the debugger and watch what IntelliJ thinks the values are, it displays `â\u0080\u0099 â\u0080\u009C â\u0080\u009D` and it seems that `â\u0080` are nonprinting characters.

I used a piece of code that iterates over a StringBuilder of the text in the field and tests each char in the text. It replaces or deletes some chars, as below:

```
switch (origCharAsInt) {

    case ((int)'\u00C2'): sbOriginal.deleteCharAt(isb); break; // weird Word A with the caret over it
    case ((int)'\u00C3'): sbOriginal.deleteCharAt(isb); break; // weird Word A with the tilde over it
    case ((int)'\u00E2'): sbOriginal.deleteCharAt(isb); break; // weird Word a with the caret over it

    case ((int)'\u0099'): sbOriginal.setCharAt(isb, '\''); break; // Word single quote
    case ((int)'\u009C'): sbOriginal.setCharAt(isb, '"'); break; // Word left double quote
    case ((int)'\u009D'): sbOriginal.setCharAt(isb, '"'); break; // Word right double quote

    case ((int)'\u2018'):  sbOriginal.setCharAt(isb, '\''); break;  // left single quote
    case ((int)'\u2019'):  sbOriginal.setCharAt(isb, '\''); break;  // right single quote
    case ((int)'\u201A'):  sbOriginal.setCharAt(isb, '\''); break;  // lower quotation mark

    case ((int)'\u201C'):  sbOriginal.setCharAt(isb, '"'); break;  // left double quote
    case ((int)'\u201D'):  sbOriginal.setCharAt(isb, '"'); break;  // right double quote
    case ((int)'\u201E'):  sbOriginal.setCharAt(isb, '"'); break;  // double low quotation mark

    case ((int)'\u2039'):  sbOriginal.setCharAt(isb, '\''); break;  // Single Left-Pointing Quotation Mark
    case ((int)'\u203A'):  sbOriginal.setCharAt(isb, '\''); break;  // Single right-Pointing Quotation Mark

    default: break;
```

}

This seems to work, in that it replaces some of the more egregious cruft, and the form now appears to contain `' " "`. If I then save again, though, the IntelliJ thinks the field contains `Â\u0080 Â\u0080\" Â\u0080\"`.

So I added a few more cases to remove those Â characters. But I'm flummoxed by the persistence of the `\u0080` characters.

I tried adding in a few more cases to try to remove them, but they did not work.

```
case ((int)'\u0080'): sbOriginal.deleteCharAt(isb); break; // another weird Word non-printing char
case ((int)'\u0082'): sbOriginal.deleteCharAt(isb); break; // another weird Word non-printing char
case ((int)'\u0083'): sbOriginal.deleteCharAt(isb); break; // another weird Word non-printing char
case ((int)'\u0000'): sbOriginal.deleteCharAt(isb); break; // why are these weird symbols showing up?
```

Any help/explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note: I found the code block above at http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?72944-How-to-handle-Smart-Quotes-pasted-into-TextArea-input

Comment: An additional note: Looking in the database, I see that this is the text that is saved (post all munging I can think of): `€' €" €"` Clearly I'm dealing with a variety of encoding schemes but WTF.

Comment: So far I have also tried `description.replaceAll("\\p{C}", "");` and `description.replaceAll("![:print:]", "");` to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape HTML properly.  Unicode isn't the answer here.  [This link](http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php) is your jam.

Comment: The issue is that my users edit text in Word and copy paste it into my form, and when it gets to my validation (in Java) it shows up as this Unicode stuff. Where in the flow are you suggesting that I escape HTML?

Comment: Yeah, waiting for a reply too !

Comment: You need to encode what goes into the HTML form POST.  That's HTTP 101.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this doesn't work (inside the above switch) (and would welcome an explanation):

```
case ((int)'\u0080'): sbOriginal.deleteCharAt(isb); break;
```

but this does:

```
description = description.replaceAll("\u0080", "");
```